# Scheduled Task Priority and Paging problems

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, virtual-memory, pagefile, priority

I just scheduled a task in my Windows 7, and I have 2 problems with it:

1. The process starting with Below Normal priority.
2. Even after manually changing the priority to Normal (via Task Manager), the process's memory going to the pagefile when idle.

Both problems aren't happening when running the same process without scheduled task.

How to make the scheduled task run with Normal priority and without paging the memory?

Thanks.

Comment: Process priority does not affect whether the "process's memory goes to the pagefile".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the task's priority in the GUI, but you can change it in it's XML by exporting the task. After you've exported the task open the XML in Notepad or your favorite text editor. Somewhere in the file, probably near the bottom, look for the Priority element and change its value. The default value is 7. Valid values are between 0 and 10 inclusive with 0 being the highest priority and 10 being the lowest priority. (Go figure!)  After you've changed the Priority element save the file, delete the scheduled task from Task Scheduler and import the fixed up XML file.

The schema for scheduled tasks is documented at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383609(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383609%28VS.85%29.aspx). The Priority element itself is documented at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383070(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383070%28VS.85%29.aspx)